# How to remove first value of range in each iteration?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to use a for loop before while loop and define a range and in each iteration, I would like to remove the first value of for loop

the results that I would like to get after first iteration is
h will be in the range(1, 30), next iteration(2,30) and until the end.
 The reason is my while loop doesn't use other values and only use the first value, I would like to use all 30 numbers

Comment: So your code has another outer loop which is not included here? What is the significance of the inner while loop?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to "remove the first value of for loop", as that loop is already defined.  I think we need a little more info about what you're trying to do. -seeing @meowgoesthedog 's question, I have the same question in my head.  Is there an outer loop, so you want the list this for loop is operating on to get smaller each time through the outer loop?

Comment: this code is an example, Actually my real code, at first was defined with while, and there was a parameter beta which i defined at the beginning of algorithm, and i opened the while loop and it calculated the data with the given beta, however i would like to place different beta with for loop and see different results but the results were all the same it means that the while loop after for loop doesn't use all the values, that's why i wanted to remove first values after each iteration to use different beta

Comment: @steve, how can i show you my real code , this was an example, because my code was so long, i put it yesterday and nobody responded?

Comment: maybe you can't.  what you need to do is distill it down so you can point at THE problem.  In what you have so far, it still isn't clear to me what you want to do. - I think maybe I've got a hint of it, but still unclear

Comment: @steve actually, I am working on an algorithm, At the beginning I defined a parameter beta=200, and after that there was an algorithm with a while loop which checked a condition over many iteration and then calculated something. however the next task was to change values of beta, and see the results, so

Comment: what i did was to to define a for loop before while loop and see the results and tried to store values in array. however all the results were similar, it meant something went wrong, maybe while loop doesn't use the values in the for loop and maybe only used the first value. that's why it came to my mind to remove first value after each iteration... this is the whole story

Comment: @steve I shared my code here in the answers, you can see what i want, I ran this algorithm for beta=50 but right now i define a for loop for different beta before while loop, but doesn't work, i don't know what's my problem, the results are all the same

Comment: We need a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing what you are trying to do so I won't write any code but a logic is simple: put the code you have inside another for loop with variable i - from 0 to 30, then in you current code change 0 to i. This way, your inner loop will iterate from 0 to 30, then 1 to 30, 2 to 30 and so on.

Comment: This assumes that "np.arange(0, 30)" produces the same thing as "range(0, 30)".  No reason to assume it does...or is there?  I, at least, have no idea what "np" is.

Comment: @Steve `np` is how the vast majority of people name `numpy` after importing.

Comment: Oh, then I probably misunderstood the question. I don't code in python and somehow I though it was just basic for loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a range, or a list of numbers, you could simply declare a variable before the while loop, e.g. `i = 0`, and in the while loop point it at the index of the number in the list that you want to work on. At the end of the while loop, increment `i`.

You'd have something like this:

```py
foo = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
i = 0
while i < len(foo) :
    number_to_process = foo[i]
    *operations on number_to_process*
    i += 1
```